# Laravel Homestead upgrade from 5.2 to 5.3 errors

Tags: php, windows, laravel, homestead

I have a very simple setup that works with Win10, homestead, and laravel 5.2 and VirtualBox 5.0.26 r108824. I spent some time on basic setup, like environment files, config etc, and I dont want to redo all this and start totally fresh for the 5.3 laravel update. My simple route I have working is nothing so I can easily manually copy that to a new laravel 5.3 install. What is the best way to migrate from 5.2 in this case?

I've already done a homestead update that I think worked ok.

I did a simple composer.json update ( the file on my VM in my working project directoy on Ubuntu ) copied form laravel github here

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*"
},
```

"
My previous composer.json from Windows directory is:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "symfony/console": "~2.3|~3.0",
    "symfony/process": "~2.3|~3.0"
},
```

and had errors as below:

Declaration of App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::boot(Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher 
events) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider::
oot()

cript php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]
 Error Output:

I backed up total current working setup. No worries of breaking anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow the upgrade guide from 5.2 to 5.3.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

That guide tells you all you need to know and do.
If you have it so simple, maybe many of the things would not apply for you and you just read them and pass them, but you sure need to go through the guide, step by step and applying any changes you need to do.

That is the official way to do it, and any other advice would probably let something out and you end up with errors.

Comment: Thank you. That article would help more if I had a few routes and needed to migrate to 5.3. I only had the splash page in my 5.2 install. It took many hours getting all the config files right and ports forwarded etc. I was hoping there was a simple way to upgrade to 5.3 in my simple case.